# How can I create message boxes dependent upon entries in certain cells?

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to check whether certain boxes are checked complete.

- If any of the boxes are marked incomplete, prompt the user with a warning message.
- If all are marked complete, move on to the next step in the overall macro.

```vb
Sub check_complete()

Dim x As Integer

For x = 10 To 19

    If Cells(x, 16).Value = "Complete" Then
    End If

    If Cells(x, 16).Value = "Incomplete" Then
        Result = MsgBox("We noticed that you have not uploaded all of the data.  Would you still like to continue?", vbYesNo + vbExclamation, "Error: Incomplete Data")
        If Result = vbYes Then
        End If

    Else
    
    End If

    If Cells(x, 16) <> "Complete" <> "Incomplete" Then
        Result = MsgBox("We noticed an error in your checklist." & vbNewLine & "The checklist items should be marked as Complete/Incomplete." & vbNewLine & vbNewLine & "Would you like to continue anyway?" & vbNewLine & "(Doing so may create issues in finalizing your data)", vbYesNo + vbExclamation, "Error: Incomplete Data")

        If Result = vbYes Then
        End If

    Else

    End If

Next x
End Sub
```

The code refers to a group of cells that either contain the text "Complete" or "Incomplete".
As the user moves through the group of macros, the cells automatically change from Incomplete to Complete.
If they skip a step, I would like to warn them.

Comment: A macro won't "wait" for a step to be done. A macro is triggered by "something". For example a button. You need to consider your workflow here. For example if you have a "submit button" at the bottom, that is the time to run a validation macro and check which fields are updated.

Answer (score 0):

Edit: I tinkered around with the code and found the answer to my own question.  I figured I would share in case anyone ever has this question in the future.

My newly corrected [working] code is as follows:

```
Sub check_complete()
Dim x As Integer
Dim y As Integer

Sheets("Updating Data").Select

x = 10
y = 19
On Error GoTo eh

Do While x < y
Cells(x, 16).Select
If Selection.Value = "Incomplete" Then
    Err.Raise Error_INVALID_DATA, "Updating Data", "Data upload not complete"
End If
x = x + 1
Loop
Done:
    Exit Sub
eh:
    Result = MsgBox("We noticed that you have not uploaded all of the data.  Would you still like to continue?", vbYesNo + vbExclamation, "Error: Incomplete Data")
            If Result = vbYes Then
                On Error Resume Next
            Else:
                End
End If

End Sub
```